# How to fix TinyMCE 'Domain not registered' message in an Electron app?

Tags: electron, tinymce, tinymce-5

The problem is, the editor shows that "*domain not registered*" message. My *api key is correct*. I have to hide the message via css, that cannot be the solution. The editor initialization (I'm using *React*):

```
<div className="input textarea">
  <Editor
    apiKey={'aodqx0v...'}
    onInit={(evt, editor) => descriptionEditorRef.current = editor}
    initialValue={field.value}
    onEditorChange={(value, editor) => { field.onChange(value); helpers.handleChangeItemEditor(value, current_formState, 'description'); }}
    init={{
      inline: true,
      height: 500,
      menubar: false,
      plugins: [
        /* 'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount' */
      ],
      toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
        'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
        'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
        'removeformat | help',
      content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    }}
  />
</div>
```

Right now I'm still working locally (on localhost), so I checked the approved domains list. Localhost IS in the list.
[image: localhost included]

Hm. I re-checked it now, the problem is gone. No changes in code, strange.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your domain is on your approved domain list here: https://www.tiny.cloud/my-account/domains/

More info: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/this-domain-is-not-registered-with-tiny-cloud/

Comment: localhost is approved by default. https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/this-domain-is-not-registered-with-tiny-cloud/
Anyway I checked this and updated my answer.